# Javascript Json Parse

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Json in javascript. I'm reading the json from test.js. How can I read `for(;;)`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $.getScript('ajax/test.js', function(data, textStatus){
        jQuery.each(data, function(return) {
            alert(return.name);
            alert(return.surname)
        });
    });
    </script>
```

-

TEST JS

```
for (;;);
{
 "name"     : "Mustafa Can",
 "surname"  : "Pala"
};
```

Comment: Can you please clear this up? What does `How can I read for(;;)` mean?

Comment: Change test.js, because that's just not valid JSON.

Comment: @Matt: It's an anti-XSS technique

Comment: @SLaks really? `[citation-needed]`

Comment: @Matt: It prevents attackers from including the JSON in a script tag after defining property setters so they can intercept the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `$.get` to fetch the content of the script as a string, then remove the `for(;;);`:

```
$.get('ajax/test.js', function(data, textStatus){
    var json = data.replace(/^for\(;;\);/, "");
    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);

    alert(obj.name);
    alert(obj.surname)
}, 'text');
```

Comment: @Gürkan: To prevent jQuery from parsing it as JSON (which would fail) or executing it as Javsacript (which would freeze)